# Missing texture after Build & Run for iOS in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Whenever I start Build & Run for iOS, some textures went missing. After then, I reset my code repository and doing it again. But still, some textures were missing and this time, it's different textures. I've tried to build on different Macs and different version of XCode, so it seems that the problem lies on the Unity itself.
I've search the internet for this issue, but still I haven't found any solution that works.
I've also tried to build for Android, and I don't have that problem.

Can anybody give me any pointer regarding this issue?
I'm using Unity 4.3.4.

Best regards,

Aries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem has been found.
This problem didn't occurs after the Unity3D is downgraded to 4.3.0.
It seems this is a bug on Unity 4.3.4.